# How to use two parskips?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip

I'll go straight to the point. I'm using the `parskip` package, in particular with this option `\setlength{\parskip}{0.3\baselineskip plus2pt minus2pt}`.

This code:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

produces this:
[image: Code render]

However, I would like to make the `\newline` (or `\\` in my example) command to show a bigger skip. Using `\\ \\` as a workaround, works fine and renders well, but I get some *Underfuill hbox* error.

My question is this: how can I configure the `\newline` paragraph skip or what is the proper way to accomplish it?

Comment: Don't do that.  Use `\bigskip` or create your own command.

Comment: ...or `\medskip` or `\smallskip`. These work in vertical mode, so you need to have a empty line before them.

Comment: @Werner -- Ha.  Just realized I should mention them too...

Comment: Thanks, guys I ended up defining my own command. I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: “If something apparently simple is difficult to do in LaTeX, it's probably typographically bad”. This is a case: there's *rarely* need for a vertical space between paragraphs.

Comment: @egreg you are probably right, but I needed those two paragraph kinds for a particular document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jon and @Werner suggested, instead of using `\\ \\`, `\bigskip` (or `\medskip` and `\smallskip`) shall be used instead. However, as those work in vertical mode, an empty line must lie before the command itself (if you just use `\bigskip`) you will get weird results.

So that, I ended making my own command to avoid the indentation:

```
\newcommand{\customskip}{\bigskip\noindent}
```

which produces, as intended, this text:

[image: Customskip]

Comment: This is definitely not recommended.  Use `\newcommand{\customskip}{\bigskip\noindent}` if you want to impose vertical space *and* not indent the new paragraph.  Adding whitespace between paragraphs is the normal way to start a new paragraph; and it helps make your input file more readable.  Why do you want to avoid doing it?

Comment: Oh, actually I don't know. Now that I think about it, my command and attitude about whitespace is rather stupid. Your solution sounds a lot better and logical.